# Use GEE downloading worldwide images results in a very narrow line

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("projects/verselab-398313/assets/HiQ_LAI/wgs_500m_8d");
var MODTSS = imageCollection.filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-12-31').select('Re_TSS_MOD');
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive( MODTSS, 'MODIS2018', {
scale: 500
})
```

I downloaded the image using the above code, and I made sure that the imageCollection data is fine, it's global data, and the 'RE_TSS_MOD' band is global data. When downloading, the default projection is EPSG:3857, and I changed it to EPSG:4326. What's the problem?
The downloaded image is opened in ArcGIS and the result is shown in the figure below：

[image]
Results from browsing on GEE：
[image]
The properties of the data are shown in the following figure
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a degenerate region collapsed to the anti-meridian.
Specify a region in the export as a 6-point polygon spanning the globe.

```
var WORLD = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-180, 88, 0, 88, 180, 88, 180, -88, 0, -88, -180, -88], null, false)
```